# Where can I find these libraries to install in Ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

Here is some information saying some libraries are needed to build [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) for programming:

> -- checking for module 'libunicap'
>
> --   package 'libunicap' not found
>
> -- checking for module 'libucil'
>
> --   package 'libucil' not found
>
> -- checking for module 'libv4l1'
>
> --   package 'libv4l1' not found

I tried to look it up in [Synaptic Package Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29) but did not find any. Any advice?

---

UPDATE:

I am installing OpenCV 2.0 via [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), following http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide.

Comment: +1 Because you're using Ubuntu

Comment: I do an up vote to your question because of that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following [these instructions](http://dircweb.king.ac.uk/reason/opencv_cvs.php#Hardy) which tell you how to install dependencies and build OpenCV on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and installed the libraries "libgtk2.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev" already. Note I am installing opencv 2.0 via cmake, not quite the same as the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Ubuntu Canonical Repository](http://ns2.canonical.com/)?

Because I searched there and I got the [libucil](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ro/karmic/libucil2) (I tested only with it).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have. I downloaded them and got "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: llbucil2" like error. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I don't have any idea and my Ubuntu laptop isn't here with  me now to test this to you. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really belong here but you can try using [aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) which should fetch the dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude update # just update in case you haven't in a long time.
sudo aptitude install OpenCV
```

Just replace OpenCV with the actual package name of OpenCV. Not sure what it is.